# How to list all possible combinations of the values in three columns in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have three columns, each of which has different kinds of master data as shown below:

[image]

Now, I want to have all possible combinations of these three cells - like

```
aa kk jj
aa kk ff
aa ll jj
aa ll ff
aa mm jj
...
```

Can this be done with a formula. I found one formula with 2 columns, but i'm not able to extend it to 3 columns correctly

Formula with 2 columns:

```
=IF(ROW()-ROW($G$1)+1>COUNTA($A$2:$A$15)*COUNTA($B$2:$B$4),"",
INDEX($A$2:$A$15,INT((ROW()-ROW($G$1))/COUNTA($B$2:$B$4)+1))&
INDEX($B$2:$B$4,MOD(ROW()-ROW($G$1),COUNTA($B$2:$B$4))+1))
```

where G1 is the cell to place the resulting value

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46101847/excel-permutation-table-without-vba).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel Permutation Table without VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46101847/excel-permutation-table-without-vba)

Comment: @pnuts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48658504/excel-convert-us-date-format-to-european-format

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with a formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,IF(INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/(((COUNTA(B:B)-1)*((COUNTA(C:C)-1)))))+2>COUNTA(A:A),-1,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/(((COUNTA(B:B)-1)*((COUNTA(C:C)-1)))))+2))&" "&INDEX(B:B,MOD(INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/(COUNTA(C:C)-1)),(COUNTA(B:B)-1))+2)&" "&INDEX(C:C,MOD((ROW(1:1)-1),(COUNTA(C:C)-1))+2),"")
```

[image]

Comment: The formulas you create are a work of art. You really should have a museum named after you imho. xD

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs you are too kind, and there are people that put me to shame on a regular basis, I am just more prolific than they.

Comment: need [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550006/how-to-list-all-possible-combinations-of-the-values-in-five-columns-in-excel) on the explanation/extension..

Comment: For me, this formula creates only the first entry. The entries below are empty, even if I copy the formula there. Could you please offer an Excel file for download?