# Excel: Convert US date format to European format

Tags: excel, date

I have the following US date format `5/30/2018 8:00:00 AM`. I am looking for an optimized formula to convert it into European format `30/05/2018` (dd/mm/yyyy) without the time. I have searched the net for a good solution, was not able to find an easy one. I am looking for a formula and not to format cells etc

Moreover my computer is set for European format, which reads months and days wrongly. Any changes in excel to overcome this situation would be helpful.

This question is not for VBA but i am requesting a formula to be entered in a cell. Also the source cell is not formatted as a number/date... its just a general cell or custom cell

Comment: If you dont want to format cells means, Then whatelse you need ?

Comment: First it is *'I am looking for an optimized formula ...'* then it is *'I am not looking for a formula...'*. Which is it?

Comment: sorry, my mistake while typing. I have edited the question. Thank you

Comment: @Jeeped This question has been edited to specifically mention not using VBA. Is this still a duplicate?

Comment: @Rob - Yes. Worksheet formula and other worksheet operation  solutions are discussed in several of the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the meantime, I came up with this formula

`=IF(ISNUMBER(A2),VALUE(TEXT(A2,"mm/dd/yyyy")),DATE(MID(A2,FIND("/",A2,FIND("/",A2)+1)+1,4),LEFT(A2,FIND("/",A2)-1),MID(A2,FIND("/",A2)+1,(FIND("/",A2,FIND("/",A2)+1)-FIND("/",A2)-1))))`

Any other optimized formulas are welcome

Comment: this is working great i am using this formula in my files

Comment: happy to hear its working and can be used as a generic formula

Answer (score 1):

this will fix it

`=TEXT("9/1/2017 12:00:00 AM","dd/mm/yyyy")`

you can change accordingly

Comment: sorry have tried this. This works only if the cell is a number/date, it does not work for me I get a #value when i use this formula

Comment: @PrashantBalasubramanyan You should have probably explained this in your question then. Anyways, I am sure this will help someone else in the long run (unlike OP & his vague question), so +1