# How to find permutation of 2 elements to n column with each row combination being unique

Tags: excel, vba, permutation

I am writing a VBA excel code to find the all different combinations for 2-level factors. Each factor would have 2 possible levels. For example, if i have 3 factors the number of possible combinations of levels would be `2^3 = 8`. My goal is to print out the 8 combinations in Excel.

For example, my factors(levels) are `Weight(50,60)` and `height(160,170)` unique combinations would be

```
50,160
50,170
60,160
60,170
```

with weight in column A and height in column B

My question would be is it possible to write out a VBA code to print out all the possible combinations for factors (ranging from 2-12)  and code should be written in excel VBA

Comment: Since you are writing code, would you please add it to your post and turn it into an actual question?

Comment: And please add more example data (at least 3 or 4 factors) for better understanding.

Comment: **Start Here:**  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48651400/how-to-list-all-possible-combinations-of-the-values-in-three-columns-in-excel

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tiny example for **two factors** using nested loops:

```
Sub Kombination()
    Dim N As Long, M As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim K As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    M = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    K = 2

    For i = 2 To N
        For j = 2 To M
            Cells(K, 3).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value & "," & Cells(j, 2).Value
            K = K + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Once you have determined the number of factors, modify the code to nest at that level.