# Expand each item in a list in Excel with all variations in a second and third list

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have an excel file that has three columns - on column 1 I have a list of words, and on column 2 I have a list of attributes the prepended, while on column 3 I have a list of attributes to be appended.

How can I create a single list with all concatenations of attributes to be appended and prepended?

For example, I have words such as:

- Cumin
- Oregano
- Turmeric

Prepend terms such as

- recipes with
- benefits of
- substitute for

and Append terms such as

- recipes
- uses
- powder

... and I would like to have an automated way of joining these to get:

- recipes with cumin
- benefits of cumin
- substitute for cumin
- cumin recipes
- cumin uses
- cumin powder
- ...

Comment: just to be clear, each of the three columns don't always need to be present. so the spice can have an appended AND/OR a prepended phrase (either or both)?

Comment: I have about 50 attributes to be prepended and 30 attributed to be appended. Each new line item created should be a result of appending OR prepending, not both. I am ok with generating two lists as well if it's easier - one of prepended words + attributes, and another of appended words + attributes.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48651400/how-to-list-all-possible-combinations-of-the-values-in-three-columns-in-excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A1:A&CHAR(9)),COUNTA(B1:B)),CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(B1:B&CHAR(9),COUNTA(A1:A))),CHAR(9)));
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(B1:B&CHAR(9)),COUNTA(C1:C)),CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(C1:C&CHAR(9),COUNTA(B1:B))),CHAR(9)))})
```

[image]