# Combine excel rows

Tags: excel

I am looking for simple way to combine data in excel sheet. I want to avoid  adding rows manually.
Could You give me a hint how to do this simple way?
[image]

Comment: have a look [here]().. try the solution proposed in the comments and post. Then share if helps or where you stuck at (upon) trying.

Comment: Can not see link

Comment: This can be done through power Query

Comment: @OskarGroth sorry.. I missed it.. here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59292206/how-to-create-a-one-to-many-relationship

Answer (score 2):

Manually place the headers in **H1**, **I1**, and **J1**.  Then in **H2** enter:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$9999,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/(COUNTA(C:C)-1),0))
```

amd copy downwards.  In **I2** enter:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$9999,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,COUNTA(C:C)-1)+1)
```

and copy downwards.  In **J2** enter:

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$9999,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,COUNTA(D:D)-1)+1)
```

and copy downwards.

[image]